# how to make custom layered filter rules active by default?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

Is it possible to do it programmatically and how ?

For example I need a basic price filter rule active on catalog from 0 to 500 USD (in real world i need customize custom layered filter model), so when i log in as customer and browse category, it only shows products which prices in this range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default parameter in the category URL : `http://www.website.com/category?price=40-60` for example.
That will be a specific development.

I suggest you to take at the following function : `apply()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php` if you want to set it up in the `Layers` and functions `addFilter()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/State.php`
OR
In `getCategoryUrl` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Url.php` if you want to set it up directly in the category URL